# R: converting from matrix.csr to dense matrix

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have downloaded a dataset from LIBSVM and read it in using the `e1071` function `read.matrix.csr`. This loads it as a `SparseM` `matrix.csr` object. But now I'm stuck as I can't figure out how to convert this object to a dense matrix.

Is there an easy way to convert a `SparseM` `matrix.csr` object to a standard `R` dense matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, if `X` is a sparse matrix then `as.matrix(X)` will convert it to a dense matrix.